# SQL Server locking and multiple session id issue

Tags: database, sql-server-2008-r2

I migrated a database over the weekend and I have run into some locking errors. I'm not exactly sure where to look to see if I can get this resolved, but here is what I know.

I restored a database from SQL Server 2005 to SQL Server 2008 SR2 and added the security login user and left the default database as 'master' (same as SQL2005). Everything checked out fine during my testing last week and I was able to log in through the application no problems.

However when I went to do the major move (another restore where I overwrote all the data) I was no longer able to log in through the application without modifying the security login default database to 'DBLive'. ('DBLive' is the production database and 'DBTest' is the test database)

If I log into 'DBLive' I end up with two user sessions in the activity monitor. And if I continue to use the program I end up with database locks (randomly) when using the program. Sometimes its a typical select query and other times its an update or a delete.  It's not the same thing each time and I can't duplicate it other than it happens and I can see it's locked in the activity monitor. If I do the same action, sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't.

If I log into 'DBTest' there is only one session created for the user and I have not been able to duplicate the problem on it.

So by the deductive reasoning it has to be something related to the database. I've compared the properties of the databases, the user permissions and schemas and everything matches.

Since I didn't have log in troubles until after the second restore. I'm thinking maybe I corrupted something, but I don't know what that something is. I restored 'DBtest' from the same restore .bak file.

The other thing I found is if I change the default db to 'DBtest' when I log in through the application and say I want 'DBlive' it logs me into 'DBtest' with two sessions.

So my question to everyone is does anyone have any idea on how I can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm still not sure of the exact cause but I ended up creating a backup of 'DBlive' and restoring it to a new db. 'NewDB' worked as it was supposed to with out the multiple sessions. However if I renamed the 'NewDB' to 'DBlive' the issue occurred again, so I renamed it back to 'NewDB'.

I believe the issue is related to the Default database option somewhere in the system files. As long as I don't have a database called 'DBlive' everything functions as it should.

So the cause of the issue I am 'assuming' was since I restored the 'DBlive' first off from the 2005 SQL back up file and then restored it again from a 2005 SQL backup file (when I was moving it completely) that the 2008 server made some sort of modification while restoring the file and duplicated the same modification when I overwrote the initially restored db.